# Refactoring - How to prevent refactorings tab showing?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe

In Delphi XE, I use the rename variable refactoring (Ctrl+Shift+E) a lot of the time to make my code easier to understand by giving more meaningful variable names, for example:

[image]

That is all good but I have one slight issue regarding workspace when I use this. I like to keep the code messages etc pinned to the bottom, they only appear when I hover my mouse over them - this is my preference to allow more space for the editor.

Now, when I use the rename variable refactoring, the dialog has the checkbox: `View references before refactoring` as shown from the image above. I have this unchecked as I generally don't need to oversee what is been changed etc, if needs be I just undo it.

Here is my issue, with that unchecked I would of hoped for the refactoring to of performed silently, but no I still get the refactorings window showing up underneath:

[image]

It might not be considered a major issue but every time I have to manually close the refactorings window is just wasting time and is becoming a nuisance.

I noticed if you click on the refactorings tab in the editor there is an option to hide, but this is not permanent as it will come back the next time you refactor anyway.

Is there an option I may have missed somewhere to prevent the refactorings window from displaying in the code editor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *…to prevent the refactorings window from displaying **in the code editor***

How about moving it elsewhere? Undock it from the bottom of the editor window and dock it at a different place. (Unless you've hidden *all* the side panels.)

Comment: ...and then save that as your default desktop.  I dock mine in the message pane.

Comment: I think I will drag it somewhere else then, I thought there might be an option somewhere to permanently hide it (browsing all the environmental options is not always easy!)